# Два объекта типа "class" в одном файле, как заставить работать?

Tags: java

```
public class Test20 {

    int summa(int a, int b, int c ) {
        int result = a + b + c;
        return result;
    }
}
class Test21{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test20 t = new Test20();
        int summaTrexChisel = t.summa(1, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(summaTrexChisel);
    }
}
```

Изучаю Java по видео урокам с помощью программы Eclipse. При попытке создать более 1 класса в файле, код при запуске ничего не выдаёт. Хотелось бы узнать, как это исправить и где я ошибся при написании кода?

UPD/.
Полазил в настройках и немного уточню. Запускаю сам код кнопкой – Run (Ctrl + F11). При этом если в коде 2+ объекта типа “class”, то при запуске Eclipse не реагирует на этот код и в поле Console выводит текст с последнего рабочего кода (с 1 объектом “class”) который запускался в программе.
То есть чтобы мне запустить код с 2 объектами “class” нужно его запускать через Run configuration => Main class указать “class” который нужно запустить и делать так каждый раз иначе см. выше. Извините объяснил как смог, если что-то не понятно спрашивайте я уточню.

Comment: `При попытке создать более 1 класса в файле` ну так не пытайтесь это делать, пишите по 1 классу на файл.

Comment: Должно работать, главное указать Test21 как главный класс. Ошибки в консоли выдает? Включите в текст вопроса если да.  Чтоб помочь - нужно знать как именно запускаете (есть много способов и от этого зависит куда смотреть и как исправлять, опишите какой пункт меню или кнопку на тулбаре или через контекстное меню используете)? Какой класс указан как главный в Run Configuration (если знаете как посмотреть)? Все это добавьте кнопкой "править" в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указывать более одного класса в файле весьма плохая практика. Но раз так, то поменяйте местами определения классов:там, где метод main, класс должен быть public, в первую очередь. И тогда поменяйте имя файла на Test21

Comment: Благодарю, помогло! Что-то сам не додумался до такого варианта. По поводу того, что указывать более одного класса в файле я слышал. Но т.к. только начал изучать Java толком не понимаю, как это обойти, поэтому продолжаю читать туториалы.